# Dampened Sound after unplugging headphones

Tags: windows-7, laptop, audio, windows-10, speakers

Everytime after I unplug my headphones my speaker sounds are getting damped.

It was like this for a long time, but on Windows 7 it was fixed by simply changing the loudness.
Now I upgraded to Windows 10 and this fix doesn't work anymore.

I am using a Acer Aspire 5950G laptop, and it seems like only one speaker is being used. It has Realtek HD Audio speakers.